# Visual Studio Code is not npm start-ing my React JS app when debugging

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I want to debug a React JS app on Visual Studio Code so i'm following this tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial

I'm stuck at:

> Ensure that your development server is running ("npm start"). Then
>   press F5 or the green arrow to launch the debugger and open a new
>   browser instance.

A new Chrome instance is being opened requesting "http://localhost:3000" but my app is not really running, it seems it just ran the debugger.

If i mannually `npm start` my app it runs. So i guess that `launch.json` is missing something for Visual Studio Code to start the app with the debugger. That's why i'm stuck at ensuring that my development server is running the command, because i don't know where exactly i check this

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `preLaunchTask` in your **launch.json** to automatically run `npm start`.

Create **tasks.json** in **.vscode** folder.

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "custom",
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "ˆ$"
                },
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": "Compiling...",
                    "endsPattern": "Compiled .*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Press **F5** to start debugger, `npm start` will be executed.

Comment: Code-only answers are not encouraged, please add some context to explain how this answer will solve the problem in question.

Comment: Nice. Switching the selected answer to this one since this does exactly what I needed at that time

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's even possible. The tutorial clearly says you should ensure that the development server already runs. So, you'll have to first run `npm start`and debug afterwards.